# How can I create a realistic floor water fountain

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am trying to create a water fountain (as shown in the image). But for some reason after baking, all my inflows ([image]UV sphere) are being interacted with each other ending up in a mess just like shown in the image.

the inflow velocity used was z 100m/s and I have used a plane as an obstacle.

I tried a few possibilities by increasing the size of the cube(domain) or by setting the parameters such as subdivision and generate particles to different values (I'm not sure if they really play a role in this part), but it didn't really work out. May I ask for suggestions on how to overcome it.

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01PmU.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try upres the Domainresolution ? 150 for example ?

Answer (score 2):

Your water is hitting the domain cube. Gravity is 32 feet per second square which is less then 10 meters per second. I don't even think fire hoses have a velocity of 100 meters per second. You are putting out way too much water, and it is hitting the top of the domain and flowing down the sides. You want it to shoot up and fall back on gravity without hitting anything.Try 10m/sec Z velocity on your inflow.

Comment: :: I tried changing the z velocity to 10m/s, 15m/s and increasing the Domain resolution as well. Now, the inflow doesn't hit the domain border anymore. But then how to increase the velocity in such a way that the inflow shoots up the water a bit faster and also further higher?

Answer (score -2):

This is the outcome of the simulation

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add at least a summary of what is shown.

Comment: sorry since I was not able to add pictures next to my description given above which was ""I tried changing the z velocity to 10m/s, 15m/s and increasing the Domain resolution as well. Now, the inflow doesn't hit the domain border anymore. But then how to increase the velocity in such a way that the inflow shoots up the water a bit faster and also further higher?                                       so i had to add pictures as an extra comment.